# Analytical solution to the multivariate CDF given multivariate pdf

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is there any way of approximating or analytically solving the below CDF (let's say even for $n\to\infty$)?

I am trying to find the below probability:
\begin{align}
     &P\left[X_{2}-X_{1} \leq 0,X_{3}-X_{1} \leq 0, X_{4}-X_{1} \leq 0 \right]\\ &= F_{\tilde{X_{2}},\tilde{X_{3}},\tilde{X_{4}}}(0,0,0)
\end{align}

Where we know all the distributions (normal with known mean and variance) and we also know that the random variables are correlated.This method of solving seems very tedious and does not generalize well if we have even more random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Find an $3\times 4$ matrix $A$ such that $$A(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)^T=(X_2-X_1,X_3-X_1,X_2-X_1)^T=(\tilde{X_2},\tilde{X_3},\tilde{X_4})^T$$

If $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)^T$ has normal distribution with expectation $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$ then $(\tilde{X_2},\tilde{X_3},\tilde{X_4})^T$ has normal distribution with expectation $A\mu$ and covariance matrix $A\Sigma A^T$.

Working with this new distribution will probably make the calculation more simple.

Comment: What if $(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},X_{4})$ are not identically distributed?

Comment: For application of what I suggest it is enough already if they have a joint normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is a valuable tool that I will keep in mind from now on. However, it will not help me with my overall problem, since at some point I would have to calculate the CDF of the above situation (where the means and deviations are known) for $n\to\infty$ (n is the number of r.v). I think that I have to find a different approach to solving this problem

Comment: You are welcome, and good luck with finding a different approach.